# How to bind a macro to a toolbar button in open office programmatically

Tags: macros, libreoffice

How to bind a macro to a toolbar button in libre office programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Example code is in Listing 5.110 of [Andrew Pitonyak's Macro Document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).  Check out all of the toolbar information in section 5.44.

It uses the [XUIConfigurationManager](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/ui/XUIConfigurationManager.html) interface.

The standard way to add a toolbar button is to [create an extension](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/Extension_Development) and then specify the new toolbar button in an `Addons.xcu` file.  The add-on can also include the macro, so it is an easy way to distribute it for other people to use.